# Migrating from jboss AS5 to JbossAS6.1

Tags: java, jboss, jms, ibm-mq, mq

I am migrating the JBOSS AS from 5 to 6 and endup with some errors

> Caused by: javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: MQJMS2008: failed to
>   open MQ queue     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueServices.getQueueOpenException(MQQueueServices.java:412)
>   [:6.0.0.0 - j000-L050519.1  ]     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSServicesMgr.getQueueOpenException(JMSServicesMgr.java:120)
>   [:6.0.0.0 - j000-L050519.1  ]     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createQReceiver(MQSession.java:6000)
>   [:6.0.0.0 - j000-L050519.1  ]     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession.createReceiver(MQQueueSession.java:278)
>   [:6.0.0.0 - j000-L050519.1  ]     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession.createConsumer(MQQueueSession.java:332)
>   [:6.0.0.0 - j000-L050519.1  ]     at
>   org.jboss.internal.soa.esb.rosetta.pooling.WrappedSession.createConsumer(WrappedSession.java:167)
>   [:]   at
>   org.jboss.internal.soa.esb.rosetta.pooling.JmsSession.createConsumer(JmsSession.java:229)
>   [:]   at
>   org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.gateway.JmsGatewayListener.prepareMessageReceiver(JmsGatewayListener.java:446)
>   [:]   at
>   org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.gateway.JmsGatewayListener.doInitialise(JmsGatewayListener.java:114)
>   [:]   ... 101 more

Comment: Looks like you are getting a security exception. What version of MQ are you running?

Comment: i am using  Websphere MQ Version 7.0.1.0

Comment: JMS queues were not configured properly. Issue Resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  If you can provide more details  of how you solved the configuration and place that as an accepted answer it may be helpful for others in the future who run into similar problems.