# javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue ---- MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2085

Tags: jboss, websphere, ibm-mq

I'm migrating an application from Websphere to JBoss EAP 6.4.

Jboss has been configured to comunincare with a MQ queue via a resource-adapter.
This is the configuration of Jboss:

```
<resource-adapters>
<resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
    <archive>
        wmq.jmsra.rar
    </archive>
    <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
    <config-property name="logWriterEnabled">
        true
    </config-property>
    <config-property name="maxConnections">
        100
    </config-property>
    <config-property name="reconnectionRetryCount">
        1000
    </config-property>
    <config-property name="traceLevel">
        6
    </config-property>
    <config-property name="traceEnabled">
        true
    </config-property>
    <config-property name="reconnectionRetryInterval">
        30000
    </config-property>
    <config-property name="connectionConcurrency">
        1
    </config-property>
    <connection-definitions>
        <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/puc.ejb.factory" enabled="true" use-java-context="false" pool-name="puc.ejb.factory">
            <config-property name="port">
                ${wmq.port:1414}
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="hostName">
                ${wmq.host:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx}
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="channel">
                ${wmq.queue.channel:CLT2SRV}
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="transportType">
                CLIENT
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="queueManager">
                ${wmq.queue.manager:MQEDFIDP}
            </config-property>
            <timeout>
                <allocation-retry>3</allocation-retry>
                <allocation-retry-wait-millis>5000</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
            </timeout>
        </connection-definition>
    </connection-definitions>
    <admin-objects>
        <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:/puc.ejb.queue" enabled="true" use-java-context="false" pool-name="puc.ejb.queue">
            <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                DATAGRAM.GG9.INVIOSMS
            </config-property>
            <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                MQEDFIDP
            </config-property>
        </admin-object>
    </admin-objects>
</resource-adapter>
```

When publishing messages on the queue I get this exception:

> **mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,177 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1) ERROR!
>   javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: MQJMS2008: impossibile aprire
>   la coda MQ 'DATAGRAM.GG9.INVIOSMS'.**
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,180 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)
>   javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: MQJMS2008: impossibile aprire
>   la coda MQ 'DATAGRAM.GG9.INVIOSMS'.
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,181 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQQueueServices.getQueueOpenException(MQQueueServices.java:860)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,182 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQQueueServices.getOutputQueue(MQQueueServices.java:689)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,183 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.JMSServicesMgr.getOutputQueue(JMSServicesMgr.java:215)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,185 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createQProducer(MQSession.java:3082)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,186 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createProducer(MQSession.java:2820)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,187 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createProducer(MQSession.java:2876)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,188 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createProducer(JmsSessionImpl.java:1232)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,189 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createProducer(MQSession.java:687)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,191 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MessageProducerWrapper.(MessageProducerWrapper.java:104)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,192 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.SessionWrapper.createProducer(SessionWrapper.java:375)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,193 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.fideuram.puc.ejb.AccodaSMS.inviaSMS(AccodaSMS.java:81)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,194 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,195 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,197 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,198 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,199 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,200 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,201 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,203 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,204 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,205 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,207 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,208 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,209 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,210 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,212 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,213 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,214 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,215 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,216 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,218 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,219 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,220 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,221 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,223 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:279)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,224 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:331)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,225 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:243)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,226 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,227 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:80)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,229 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,230 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,231 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,232 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,234 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,235 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:89)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,236 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,237 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,239 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,240 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,241 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,242 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,243 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,245 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,246 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,247 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,248 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,250 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,251 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,252 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,253 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:189)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,254 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:319)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,256 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:68)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,257 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:201)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,258 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,260 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,261 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,262 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,263 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,264 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,266 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
>
> **mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,267 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1) Caused
>   by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Codice di completamento '2',
>   ragione '2085'.**
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,268 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.base.internal.MQQueueManager.accessQueue(MQQueueManager.java:751)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,269 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQQueueServices.getOutputQueue(MQQueueServices.java:682)
>
> mar 30, 2017 - 10:50:50,271 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 1)  ... 68
>   more

In another discussion the error had been detected on the wrong configuration of the queue but does not specify what the error was (argh!).

This is the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430558/migrating-from-jboss-as5-to-jbossas6-1)

Comment: Would you please cut that irrelevant BS from the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Codice di completamento '2', ragione
>   '2085'.

Why don't you just look up the reason code in the IBM MQ Knowledge Center.  If you had done a simple search (i.e. Google), [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqsao.doc/fm12040_1.htm) would have been at the top

Comment: Thank you Roger.
Obviously I had researched the error but in my case, unlike you, are not offered this page you suggested.  This page has helped me.
I solved by omitting the field ObjectQmgrName.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that the destination name `DATAGRAM.GG9.INVIOSMS` was not found.  Make sure that `DATAGRAM.GG9.INVIOSMS` exists on the `MQEDFIDP` queue manager.  You may also need to check to se if the `CLT2SRV` channel is correct for the queue manager.